# Cannot write to Pi Samba Server Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, samba

I have been setting up a raspberry pi Samba Server, however I have not been able to write from Ubuntu 18.04.1

Here is my config file.

```
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
read only = no
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
valid users = %S

[User3]
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
comment = User3's Storage
path = /home/shares/public/User3
valid users = User3
read only = no
writeable = yes

[User2]
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
comment = User2's Storage
path = /home/shares/public/User2
valid users = User2
read only = no
writeable = yes

[User1]
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
comment = User1's Storage
path = /home/shares/public/User1
valid users = User1
writeable = yes
read only = no
```

I get the error "Permission Denied" when I try and make a dir. I connect from the "Other Locations" of the default file explorer with "smb://Server.IP.1.Here"

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT: Authentication is set to "security = user"

Comment: Do the Linux permissions allow write: "ls -al /home/shares/public"

Comment: I ended up using chmod 777 /home/shares/public as the permissions meant that the permissions were incorrect (they were "drwxr-xr-x" ). Is there a better method?